# question with improper example

Tags: discussion

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35603467/skip-lines-without-commas) and received a complete answer immediately.

The problem is that the example I used inside the question was not appropriate so I edit the question and added new data.

The question is, can I accept this answer as answer of my initial question and ask the same question again, but this time with appropriate example?

Or I need to flag the answer as "not answer"?

Comment: Is the answer you got insufficiently general that its wisdom cannot be applied to more than one example?

Comment: Dont know the answer of your quesiton :-). the answer to my question can solve lots of problems, however for some, mine included, it can or cannot be applied. I myself couldn't change it to make it work, however someone else may revise and make it work for me.

Comment: The reverse of this question (_"I answered a question and after that the OP added addtitional requirements"_) gets asked weekly, try searching. You'll need to ask a new question if you really can't figure it out from the given answer.

Comment: I agree, it is unfair that I modified the question and ask for more. I try my best to solve the problem. otherwise I will ask here again.

Comment: @CodeCaster He didn't add new requirements; the answerer posted an answer that didn't meet the original requirements, but worked for the one sample input/output provided.  The explanation of the program's requirements in the original revision still make it clear that the answer is wrong.

Comment: @Servy I now thoroughly read the question and see the "comma requirement" was already there. You're right.

Answer (score 6):

The question was specific and clear about what it wanted, and it provided an example input and expected output that was in line with that explanation.  An answerer then provided an answer that provides the expected output for the provided input *but doesn't meet the stated requirements*; it only works for the one example given.  That makes it an incorrect answer.

Editing the question to further clarify that the entirely separate logic that the answerer used is not in line with the stated requirements is perfectly fine.  You're not changing the requirements of your question, you're simply explaining why a given approach wouldn't meet those requirements.

Since the answer is clearly wrong, you obviously shouldn't accept it.

The answer isn't "Not an answer".  It *is* an answer, it's just an incorrect answer.  You don't flag incorrect answers, you just downvote them.

Comment: thank you for rephrasing my situation in more understandable way! You know why I said to not accept an answer? because usually when a question has an answer, even an unaccepted one, then it is rarely has attention of other users to have an acceptable answer.

Comment: @Woeistg I don't see that behavior in the slightest, but even if it were true you wouldn't *want* to be drawing lots of people's attention to a *clearly wrong* answer.